# Distributing 5 red balls to 3 different people. How many ways can this be done?

Tags: combinatorics

> If you have 3 different people and 5 red balls, how many ways can you distribute the balls among the people? A person is able to have all 5 balls at once and can have 0 balls.

I have drawn it out on a whiteboard and came up with 45 possible ways to distribute the 5 undestinguishable balls, and feel like this is wrong can someone help?

Comment: Google "stars and bars" for a hint.

Comment: This is the identical problem to your money to the girls problem.

Comment: Sorry, yes it is, I wanted to try it from a different angle because I wasn't getting any feedback helping me learn the subject matter. Doing this helped me clarify what i was looking for. Thank you for the help on the previous problem Doug sorry to use your time on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "stars and bars" method - you have $5$ balls (the "stars") and $3$ people to distribute them to, and you mark how they're being distributed with dividers (the "bars"). There are $6$ places to put $2$ bars, and the $2$ bars can be in the same place. **However**, the second bar should always be in the same place, or to the right, of the first bar.
$$\Large \underline{\;\;}\; \color{red}{\bullet}\;\underline{\;\;}\; \color{red}{\bullet} \;\underline{\;\;}\; \color{red}{\bullet} \;\underline{\;\;}\; \color{red}{\bullet}\;\underline{\;\;}\; \color{red}{\bullet}\;\underline{\;\;}$$
Thus, if you put the first bar in the $k$th position from the right, then there are $k$ options for where to put the second bar. Thus there are
$$\sum_{k=1}^6k=\frac{6\cdot 7}{2}=21$$
ways of putting the bars.

For example, if the people are $A$, $B$, and $C$, then here is one way of distributing the balls:

$$\Large \color{red}{\bullet}\;{\normalsize A\bigg|B}\; \color{red}{\bullet} \quad \color{red}{\bullet}  \quad \color{red}{\bullet}\;{\normalsize B\bigg|C}\; \color{red}{\bullet}$$

This would correspond to $A$ getting $1$ ball, $B$ getting $3$ balls, and $C$ getting $1$ ball. You can also have

$$\Large {\normalsize A\bigg|B\;\;B\bigg|C}\; \color{red}{\bullet}\quad  \color{red}{\bullet} \quad  \color{red}{\bullet} \quad  \color{red}{\bullet}\quad  \color{red}{\bullet}$$

which would correspond to $A$ and $B$ getting no balls, and $C$ getting all $5$ balls.

Comment: Your answer is wrong because balls are indistinguishable. So according to your way, you count $(1,3)$ and $(3,1)$ separately while they are one and the same. Actually once you add the $2^{nd}$ bar at $i^{th}$ position, the first bar has $i$ choices. So answer is $6+5+...1=21$.

Comment: @maverick: Whoops, you're quite right. I've edited my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

You want the number of solutions to $x+y+z = 5$, where $x,y,z$ are non-negative integers.

This is analogous to $x'+y'+z'=8$, where $x,y,z\geq 1$ are integers.

The classical way to approach this problem is to consider $8$ points in a line, like this:

```
._._._._._._._.
```

Next, you should separate these points into three groups. For instance, in the following diagram:

```
._.|._._.|._._.
```

we have $x'=2,y'=3,z'=3$, which corresponds to $x=1,y=2$ and $z=2$. As another example, in the diagram below:

```
.|._._._.|._._.
```

we have $x'=1,y'=4 $ and $z'=3$, which corresponds to $x=0,y=3$ and $z=2$.

In other words, you now have $7$ spaces (the '_' ) between the dots, and you need to choose $2$ of them to bear the separators (the '|' ). Hence, the answer should be $\binom{7}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $c(b, p)$ be the number of ways of distributing $b$ balls among $p+1$ people (the $+1$ is for symmetry in the parameters). So $c(0, p) = 1 = c(b, 0)$.

If $b, p > 0$, then we can count the ways where the first person gets a ball, then add on the ways where they don't. Hence:

$$c(b, p) = c(b-1,p) + c(b, p-1)$$

which basically gives you Pascal's Triangle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

So reading from the triangle, I believe the answer to your question is $c(5,2)=21$.

Comment: Your approach is wrong as you will also count cases like when you given no balls to any person. Actually, if person $p[i]$ has $b[i]$ balls, then $sum(b[i])=tot\_balls$.

Comment: @maverick: The boundary conditions ensure that we always give the remaining balls to the last person. I had confused the number of people and of balls when I originally posted, giving the wrong answer. However, I've corrected that and now get the same as the other answers.

Comment: Actually $c(b,1)$ should  be $1$ instead of $c(b,0)=1$. Otherwise you  count a way where you have balls left but no persons.

Comment: @maverick: Thanks. Once more I've had to edit it - I'd meant to define the second parameter as the number of people -1, but had written it as number of people + 1. So the boundary conditions are symmetric, giving 1 if either parameter is 0, and we need the 5,2 entry for the 5 balls, 3 people answer.